# Reading NSSlider always returns 0

Tags: objective-c

G'day,
I have been reading about NSSliders for the last hour.  Why does NSLog(@"%f",[mySlider doubleValue]) always return zero?  Reading the value from the slider into a variable should be straight forward but for some reason it doesn't.
Thanks,
Andrew.

Comment: @Trevor, I don't see where Andrew specified that he's using iOS. Given that, we should take him at his word and assume he's working in Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Good point.  I thought I was under iPhone.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes I'm just working in Cocoa.  I've coded lots of cocoa stuff for my physics teaching but not used a slider.  I assumed they would work the same way as an NSStepper but for some reason no value is returned when my sliderMoved method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried NSLog(@"%@", mySlider) ?   It's entirely possible that mySlider is nil at the point you're reading it.

Comment: Thanks.  That returns (null).  Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Have you hooked it up in interface builder as an IBOutlet?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Connect a slider in your nib to mySlider, assuming mySlider is an outlet. Or, instantiate a NSSlider yourself in code, assign it to mySlider, and add that to your view.

Comment: Thanks guys but both of these have been done.  The slider is an IBOutlet in the .h file and connected to mySlider in the NIB file.